# Android-NDK compilation and linking

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a java project and now I want to add some NDK functionality.

here is my `Android.mk`:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := android
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Wno-psabi
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := android.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

here is my `android.c`

```
#include <jni.h>  
#include <string.h>  
#include <android/log.h>  

#define DEBUG_TAG "NDK_AndroidNDK1SampleActivity"  

void Java_ru_tonybo_app_NativeRenderer_print(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jstring message) {
    jboolean isCopy;  
    const char * szMessage = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, message, &isCopy);

    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, DEBUG_TAG, "NDK:LC: [%s]", szMessage);

    (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env, message, szMessage);
}
```

here is my related java class

```
package ru.tonybo.app;

public class NativeRenderer {
    public NativeRenderer (String message) {
        print(message);
    }

    public native void print(String message);

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("android");
    }
}
```

NDK compilation through cygwin is ok

```
TonyBo@TonyBo-NoteBook /cygdrive/d/javaProjects/App_JNI/jni
$ /cygdrive/d/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build -B
Cygwin         : Generating dependency file converter script
Compile thumb  : android <= android.c
SharedLibrary  : libandroid.so
Install        : libandroid.so => libs/armeabi/libandroid.so
```

`libandroid.so` is created and placed in /libs/armeabi/libandroid.so

but when I launch the application in eclipse on the device, I got the exception `UnsatisfiedLinkError` on native call `print(message);`

What I'm missing here or doing wrong?
May be I should somehow tell eclipse to look for shared libraries, if so how to do this?

Comment: I ran your code output comes , ya the message for jni onload is also there .

Comment: It all looks good. Is there anything funny in LogCat? Is the device running ARM-v7a/Intel/MIPS instruction set by any chance?

Comment: I am using samsung galaxy tab2  http://browser.primatelabs.com/geekbench2/1084290

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your choice of **libandroid** name is not a good idea. The library **libandroid.so** exists in the system folder **/system/lib**. It is loaded into your app, and therefore your `Load()` call simply returns. If you change the name of your native library, everything will be well.

Comment: Yep, this was the problem, but I saw such naming in one of the tutorial, so I thought it was ok, but I was wrong...

Comment: `libandroid.so` appeared on Gingerbread. That's why earlier examples could use this name.

Answer (score 1):

You need to export your method properly from the shared library. Use `JNIEXPORT` and `JNICALL` macros in the method declaration:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_ru_tonybo_app_NativeRenderer_print(...)
```

Comment: I tried this just before asking here and it didn't work. So it doesn't work now either....
I saw this syntax in `hello-gl2` sample from the ndk package. But this is not used in the `hello-jni` sample. It's a bit wierd to me, can you explain what actually this macros does?

Comment: These macros do (almost) nothing in Android for ARM, but they are part of the standard JNI convention. Namely, `JNIEXPORT` makes sure that the function will be "visible" from outside the library, even if rest of the functions are [hidden](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Visibility) (good practice!). `JNICALL` is important on Intel processors, where you must specify [**cdecl**](http://ervinloh.wordpress.com/2010/01/17/calling-conventions-cdecl-and-stdcall-cc/) and not **stdcall**.